# Log4j 2: How to Use XMLLayout?

Tags: java, tomcat7, log4j2

The Log4j 2 manual states:

> An Appender uses a Layout to format a LogEvent into a form that meets
>   the needs of whatever will be consuming the log event.

Among several of the appenders in my log4j2.xjm, I have this:

```
    <RollingFile name="RollingRateFile" fileName="${sys:webapp.rollinglogspath}/${sys:webapp.name}.rate.log" filePattern="${sys:webapp.rollinglogspath}/${sys:webapp.name}.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.rate.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy min="1" max="4" />
        <XMLLayout complete="true" charset="UTF-8" compact="false"/>
    </RollingFile>
```

When Tomcat starts, I get this error:

```
2014-11-06 12:45:40,631 ERROR appender RollingFile has no parameter that matches element XMLLayout
2014-11-06 12:45:40,696 ERROR appender RollingFile has no parameter that matches element XMLLayout
```

Logging into a standard log file works great when I omit the `XMLLayout` element.  I can't seem to locate any examples of how to correclty use `XMLLayout`.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `PatternLayout` is mutually exclusive with `XMLLayout`.  When `PatternLayout` is removed, `XMLLayout` works.

Comment: which makes perfect sense as XMLLayout defines the complete pattern to be used in its DTD :)